# how to perform scroll down action(till certain limit, not with respect to element visibility) in selenium using android driver

Tags: android, selenium, scroll, appium, driver

```java
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()
    .scrollable(true).instance(0))
    .scrollIntoView(new UiSelector()
    .textContains(\""+text+"\").instance(0))");
```

This syntax is working with element visibility.
I need a syntax by which I can scroll down till certain dimensions.

Comment: What do you mean by "certain dimension"? Certain coordinates? Is there anything unique about those coordinates (an element is there or it's an edge of one)?

Comment: selenium or appium?

Comment: @AdrianJimenez he was trying to use such method `findElementByAndroidUIAutomator`, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for scrolling buy just providing you coordinates from (x,y) to where (x,y)

```
  new TouchAction(driver).press(PointOption.point(449,1830)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(1))).moveTo(PointOption.point(449, 333)).release().perform();
```

Comment: this also not working : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Coordinate [x=449.0, y=1830.0] is outside of element rect: [0,0][1080,1776]

Comment: yeah the coordinate are out of reach because you are using what i have used according to my device. get coordinates according to your device.

Comment: I have tried other coordinates too, no exception occur still scroll not happened